# Localize WiX installer which uses the Firewall extension

Tags: msbuild, localization, wix, wix-extension

I've got a WiX installer project which uses MSBuild to generate the MSI file. The WXS file includes the WiX firewall extension:

```
xmlns:fire="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/FirewallExtension"
```

I've defined two cultures in the MSBuild file with the following definition:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
   <Cultures>en-us;no-no</Cultures>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I've also added the translated resources:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="lang\Firewall_no-no.wxl" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="lang\WixUI_no-no.wxl" />
</ItemGroup>
```

These represents translation to Norwegian for the Firewall extension and the WixUI extension. When I run the build it succeeds with the en-us part, but the no-no part fails with the following error messages:

```
C:\delivery\Dev\wix30_public\src\ext\FirewallExtension\wixlib\FirewallExtension.wxs(19):
error LGHT0102: The localization variable !(loc.WixSchedFirewallExceptionsInstall) 
is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is defined.
....
```

Couple of issues: I don't know where the `C:\delivery` directory comes from. I don't have such a directory. The localization variables referenced in the error message have been translated in the Firewall_no-no.wxl file.

When I run MSBuild with more detailed information I see the following output right before the error message:

```
Task "Light"
  Command:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML v3\bin\Light.exe -cultures:no-no 
  -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML v3\bin\WixUIExtension.dll" 
  -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows I nstaller XML v3\bin\WixUtilExtension.dll" 
  -ext "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML v3\bin\WixFirewallExtension.dll" 
  -loc lang\Firewall_no-no.wxl -loc lang\WixUI_no-no.wxl 
  -out F:\Projects\MyProd\MyProj\Installer\bin\Debug\no-no\MyInstaller.msi 
  -pdbout F:\Projects\MyProd\MyProj\Installer\bin\Debug\no-no\MyInstaller.wixpdb
  obj\Debug\MyProj.wixobj
```

As the details show, the MSBuild task results in having two `-loc` parameters to the Light executable. Not sure if that would be the reason for this problem. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the reason for this error was very simple. I got the exception because I hadn't changed the `Culture="no-no"` attribute in the `WixLocalization` tag. Setting this value made the errors disappear.